How to prevent google calendar from removing old events it gets from url
I'm working with an iCalendar subscription in my application. I've added a Google calendar  using "from url" option. My app returns an ical with events that happen later than "now", so ical files do not contain older events. Each event has a unique UID.
The issue is that older events, that were added in previous url calls and are not included in new ones, are removed from calendar.
Is there a way to modify ical to only add or update events, not to remove ones that are missing in a file?
I've tried to import events manually from file and it works fine, missing in file event is not removed from calendar.
The example of ical is below, there are 6 events in the first calendar (1 - 6) and 5 events in the second one (2 - 6), so event 1 with id 'd3bbc1c2-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa' is not included.
ical 1
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//XXX//iCalServer//EN
NAME:XXX
X-WR-CALNAME:XXX
REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:PT6H
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:d3bbc1c2-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240506T144355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240507T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240507T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dbbbc1c2-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240506T144355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240508T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240508T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dcbb67cd-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240506T144355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240509T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240509T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:e4bb67cd-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240506T144355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240510T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240510T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:46c7afd8-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240506T144355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240511T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240511T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:eccff0e0-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240506T144355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240512T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240512T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

ical 2
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//XXX//iCalServer//EN
NAME:XXX
X-WR-CALNAME:XXX
REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:PT6H
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dbbbc1c2-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240507T024355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240508T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240508T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dcbb67cd-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240507T024355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240509T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240509T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:e4bb67cd-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240507T024355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240510T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240510T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:46c7afd8-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240507T024355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240511T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240511T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:eccff0e0-71fd-ee11-ac10-06e6680cadfa
DTSTAMP:20240507T024355Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240512T010000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240512T060000
SUMMARY:5th Avenue New York, NY  US
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

